# XSL-FO : How to make value expand vertically

Tags: vertical-alignment, xsl-fo

I've got a name string in my XML whose length varies. In case of a long name, it expands horizontally which I cannot afford. How can I make it grow vertically? Below is what I have.

```
<fo:table-cell font-family="Courier" font-size="10px" display-align="before"height="0.01042in" border-style="solid" border-color="green">
    <fo:block padding-top="1pt" padding-bottom="1pt" borderstyle="solid">
        <fo:inline>
            <xsl:text>USER INFORMATION</xsl:text>
        </fo:inline>
        <fo:block>
          <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        </fo:block>
        <fo:inline font-family="Courier" font-size="12px" font-weight="bold">
          <xsl:value-of select="USERNAME" />
       </fo:inline>
    </fo:block>
</fo:table-cell>
```

Comment: Try implementing the two templates in this link (http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/xmlgraphics-fop-users/200807.mbox/%3C18382089.post@talk.nabble.com%3E).

Comment: Does the column become wider than it should? Did you specify the column width of this column?

Comment: @Hobbes, yeah and I did hard code column width which is working for labels but variable are extending that width.

Answer (score 0):

I used that link posted by Joel above in comments. When I applied template exactly, it displayed strings with odd length fine but missed the last character of even length strings. I then changed the comparison from less than`&lt;` to less than or equal`&lt;=` and it worked.
Hope it will help someone.Thanks.

```
<xsl:template name="zero_width_space_1">
    <xsl:param name="data" />
    <xsl:param name="counter" select="0" />
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$counter &lt;= string-length($data)">
            <xsl:value-of select='concat(substring($data,$counter,1),"&#8203;")' />
            <xsl:call-template name="zero_width_space_2">
                <xsl:with-param name="data" select="$data" />
                <xsl:with-param name="counter" select="$counter+1" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="zero_width_space_2">
    <xsl:param name="data" />
    <xsl:param name="counter" />
    <xsl:value-of select='concat(substring($data,$counter,1),"&#8203;")' />
    <xsl:call-template name="zero_width_space_1">
        <xsl:with-param name="data" select="$data" />
        <xsl:with-param name="counter" select="$counter+1" />
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

 <xsl:call-template name="zero_width_space_1">
    <xsl:with-param name="data" select="mystring" />
</xsl:call-template>
```

Comment: The problem with the above code is that it breaks a word into two lines. The ideal would be to add new break line when a space characters appears. If not then to follow the principle described with the above code.